# Touch screen of tiny6410 not work on linux

Tags: linux, qt, arm, embedded-linux

I have tiny6410 with linux2.6.38 and my touch screen not work after i changes this file(friendlyarm-ts-input.conf). I don't know because of changing this file or not ?
but it works perfect before i do that:
at first I do that:

```
echo "TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/ttySAC3" > /etc/friendlyarm-ts-input.conf
sync  
reboot
```

then

```
echo "TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/s3c2410_serail3"> /etc/friendlyarm-ts-input.conf  
sync  
reboot
```

again not work  .
after these codes, my touch dose not work. what can i do now?
I have base Linux on it's CD. Can I use or find touch screen and re-install it or repair it?

Comment: ts-calibrate error is : TouchDevice: /dev/input/event0.Couldnt load module friendlyarm-ts-input.No raw modules loaded. and in friendlyarm-ts-input is TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/touchscreen . #TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/ttySAC3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at fist I go to dev directory on my device. then search a bout the touchscreen device name:
cat /dev/input/ and put this command for each name of the device then i find the device. then change this line in firendlyarm-ts-input.conf 
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/touchscreen-1wire
then it worked